# MySQL table.* AS reference

Tags: mysql, select, reference

I'm using joins in MySQL and I would like to make a clear distinction between all the table columns like:

`SELECT table.* AS table_reference, table2.* AS table2_reference ...`

to have a result like this:

- table.id
- table.title
- table2.id
- table2.title

is it possible somehow?

Comment: If you're asking whether you can alias multiple columns at once, you can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it by giving each column its own alias:

```
select table.id as table_id, table.title as table_title,
       table2.id as table2_id, table2.title as table2_title
from . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
SELECT table.id
     , table.title
     , table2.id
     , table2.title
FROM table_reference table 
INNER JOIN table2_reference table2 ON table.id = table2.id
```

You should use aliases that are more descriptive and relevant than `table` and `table2` but I assume that was just for the example.