# Is it possible to reference a MySQL table dynamically?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I can't find anything about dynamically referencing a MySQL table entry in my particular case. Most everything I've read leans towards it not being possible, but I'm hoping someone can prove me wrong.

Essentially, I've got multiple MySQL tables that I'm trying to pull data from on an Android app.  I want to access 2 at a time.  The 1st Table's name always stays the same, *history*.  The 2nd Table's name, however, may be different at times.  It's value is determined within the app and referenced with *:job* in my php script (I'll use *moon* for my example).  The 2nd table itself is generated dynamically through the app, so I guess I'm trying to set up a reference within a php script I have saved to a server so that I can access the 2nd Table.

Sorry for the confusing description, I hope these tables will help explain what I'm trying to get at.

**Table #1: history** (always stays the same)

```
|  site   |   code  | hours|
|---------|---------|------|
|  moon   |  first  |   1  |
|  moon   | second  |   2  |
|  moon   |  third  |   3  |
|  earth  |  fourth |   4  |
```

**Table #2: moon** (this one I want to dynamically reference)

```
|   code  | hours|
|---------|------|
|  first  |  10  |
| second  |  11  |
|  third  |  12  |
```

**And my current code:**

```
...
/*** Table #1 ***/
SELECT code, 
SUM(hours) AS total, '' AS target
FROM history 
WHERE site = :job  /* :job ends up being moon in this example */
GROUP BY code

UNION ALL

/*** Table #2 ***/
SELECT code, 
'' AS total, SUM(hours) AS target
FROM :job  /* <--- I'm trying to do something along these lines and use 'moon', or 'earth', or whatever... */
GROUP BY code

...
```

**And later I get :job from the app:** (*moon*)

```
$query_params = array(
':job' => $_POST['jobname'],
);
```

**Result I'm Looking For:** (works perfect if I directly use Table #2's name (ie *moon*) in my php file)

```
|   code  | hours|target|
|---------|------|------|
|  first  |   1  |  10  |
| second  |   2  |  11  |
|  third  |   3  |  12  |
```

The code absolutely works as expected when I replace the :job in the 2nd table with the actual name of the table.  I'm wondering if there is some way to still do it dynamically though?

Thanks for any and all advice!

I've done some pretty extensive searching and haven't come up with anything that works for me.

[Is it possible to reference a mysql table entry value from a second table entry dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541005/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-mysql-table-entry-value-from-a-second-table-entry)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html

[MySQL table.* AS reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725947/mysql-table-as-reference)

[Retrieve parent-child hierarchy from a self-referencing mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783369/retrieve-parent-child-hierarchy-from-a-self-referencing-mysql-table)

Comment: Yes, it is possible BUT you can't bind it. You can whitelist column names and then compare.